# Exception in Add Parameter To DbCommand

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

I need an update command with parameters, and for some reasons I can't use stored procedures, actually we generate update command depend on database, table and columns, the following forms are we use:

```
        string conStr = "Provider=SQLNCLI10;Server=.\\sql2008;DataBase=MyDataBase;Trusted_Connection=true;";

        DbProviderFactory dbFactory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("System.Data.OleDb");
        DbConnection dbConnection = dbFactory.CreateConnection();
        dbConnection.ConnectionString = conStr;

        DbCommand dbCommand = dbFactory.CreateCommand();
        dbCommand.CommandText = "UPDATE [Student] SET Name = @Name Where Id = @Id";

        DbParameter param1 = dbCommand.CreateParameter();
        param1.ParameterName = "@Name";
        param1.Value = "LOL";
        DbParameter param2 = dbCommand.CreateParameter();
        param2.ParameterName = "@Id";
        param2.Value = 5;

        dbCommand.Parameters.Add(param1);
        dbCommand.Parameters.Add(param2);

        dbConnection.Open();
        dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        dbConnection.Close();
```

But there is an exception:

> Must declare the scalar variable "@Name"

Where is the problem in this code? Does anyone have an idea about this?

Comment: At which point did you associate the command with the connection? Did the factory did that? Also, at which line do you get the exception?

Comment: @Nilesh Give me this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters.aspx) That's the answer, but how about `Odbc` command, is that worked like `Oledb`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you are using `System.Data.OleDb` as database provider ( regardless you are using a sql server ) you need to use the `?` as the parameter placeholder like:

```
"UPDATE [Student] SET Name = ? Where Id = ?";
```

By using the `System.Data.OleDb`provider the names of the parameters doesn`t matter anymore but you need to ensure that the occurance of the parameters match the order the parameterobjects are added to the command objects parameter collection.

EDIT:
If you want to keep the `@` as parameter placeholder you can just change this:

```
DbProviderFactory dbFactory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("System.Data.OleDb");
```

to

```
DbProviderFactory dbFactory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("System.Data.SqlClient");
```

Comment: This is what I was trying to answer but all of a sudden the post was back to the original state, without any comments or answers!

Comment: @Nilesh The answer was deleted by owner, I just be lucky to see your link

Comment: I found it: [See this one for Odbc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc.odbccommand.parameters.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try that and let me know if it works.

```
DbParameter param1 = dbCommand.CreateParameter();
param1.ParameterName.AddWithValue("@Name", Textbox1.Text);
```

or

```
DbParameter param1 = dbCommand.CreateParameter();
param1.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", Textbox1.Text);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
command.CommandText = "EXEC [dbo].[PR_GetPurchase_ProjectBUDetails] " + prjID.ToString()+ " ," + empID.ToString();
```

Hard code parameters while calling `stored procedure`. 

 This solved my issue.